# Using CSS to grab a specified class and a number of lines after it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a CSS snippet to hide ads on a website. The problem is that the content I need to hide is a line after the div with the class tag, and is completely identical to other, useful content on the page. Is it possible to grab the div with the class AND a line after it with CSS? Right now I'm just starting with

```
.ad-indicator {
    display: none ;
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. A simple example of the HTML would be a great starting point. A [MCVE] would be even better.

Comment: What do you mean by line? Is the line contained within another element, like a span or a div?

Comment: Do you mean that the class is being used multiple times and you want to hide just 1 of the divs that is using that particular class?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing an example of you HTML but the following could get you moving in the right direction.

The [::first-line](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-line) pseudo element selector selects the first line of a block element. Using this in combination with the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) will select the first line of a following block element.

```css
.ad-indicator,
.ad-indicator+ ::first-line {
  color: red;
}

.ad-indicator {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<div>Something Random</div>
<div class="ad-indicator">
  Our Target
  <p>With Some additional content</p>
</div>
<div>
  Something else <br> With Multiple lines.
</div>
```

You may need to adjust this based on the HTML structure.